# How do I bind to the click event from within the click event when I need to do it repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got code so that when you click on a word, it is replaced by another word.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.note_text').click(function(){
            $(this).remove();
            $('#note_div').append('<span class="note_text">new</span>');
            // re-applying behaviour code here
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="note_div">
    <span class="note_text">preparing</span>
</div>
```

I need the appended word to have the same click behaviour. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: in your sample I see only the text changing... why not change that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$('.note_text').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('.note_text').live('click',function(){
```

This will cause anything on your page that ever gets the class 'note_text' to have the behaviour set by .live

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `.live()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/live/)</sup> or `.delegate()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)</sup> binding for that purpose.

```
$(function() {
   $('#note_div').delegate('.note_text', 'click', function(e) {
       $(e.target).parent().append("<span class='note_text'>new</span>").end().remove();
   });
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/PkngP/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could rebind the handler:

```
function handler(){
   $(this).remove();
   $('#note_div').append("<span class="note_text">new</span>");
   $(".note_text").unbind("click");
   $('.note_text').click(handler);
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.note_text').click(handler);
});
```